# How to reuse the same component instance on different urls

Tags: angular

**Context**

I want to create a map component, which I want to reuse on various URLs. Instantiating this component is a bit time consuming, and also uses up tile requests to display the map images everytime the component is created.

**Question**

How can I reuse the same component instance on different urls when the component is nested in the tree?

On the stackblitz below, a new `ReusableComponent` is instantiated every time I switch route

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sr9stk?file=app%2Freusable.component.ts

**Note**

I know about `RouteReuseStrategy`, but this only works for top level components (i.e. the defined in routing setup)

Using angular 5.2

Comment: Would it not be possible to `import` and `export` the component through `SharedModule` (singleton)?

Comment: @12seconds Do you have an example? I tried declaring and exporting the reusable component from a shared module, but it's the same. Maybe I'm missing some options

Comment: You can only make singletons of services with NgModules. If you declare and/or export a component it's going to export component factory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kind of a hack but this was the only way I got it working

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13dj9k

Creating the Component in a service as a ComponentRef then inserting it into a directive's ViewContatiner, the directive exists on each route. The hacky part was I had to listen the NavigationStart event to detach the component before the navigation so it could be reattached on the next route.

Comment: Thanks that's kind of what I had in mind but I had no idea on how to implement it. It does not work for now with 2 directives on the same component, but nothing prevents it, right?

Comment: How do you mean? like having 2 of the same component or using the directive for 2 different reusable components?

Comment: Having 2 of the same components

Comment: Not sure, inserting the component instance into an other ViewContatiner seems to remove it from the first

Comment: I'll probably need to modify it to make it work with 2 or more  of the same component in the same tree without changing url (e.g. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5yydar?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts), but the question was just about reusing it on a different url  and your solution works for that. Thanks :)