# How to make same ng-template using directive+component+service to work in 2 ngModules?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-template

I'm trying to implement a component that has single instance that can be used in multiple routes. This can be done in single module using a template that has directive that stores the component in service. See accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49756962/how-to-reuse-the-same-component-instance-on-different-urls).

I have [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ucawky) that is copied from [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13dj9k?file=app%2Freusable-outlet.directive.ts). This works nicely when everything is in same module. However if I place the components in their own module this does not work anymore. See [not working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahxtjn). I tried to create own module for the service+component+directive, but it did not help. How this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `ReusableModule` which exports the reusable directive and the reusable component. Basically that is like an [SharedModule](https://blog.chai-jay.com/angular-core-vs-shared-modules/) which you can then import in your different feature modules.

I edited your example at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pzm4ka) and I hope that solves the problem :)

**Edit:**

If you need different instances of the `ReusableService` too you can scope it by setting `providers: [ReusableService]` in the `ReusableModule`. If you only need one instance of that service application wide, then leave the provider for this service in the app.module.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I created the module and declared them, but didn't export them in it.